# Is it Possible to read Nifi flowfile data by the help of nifi expression language?

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

Basically I want to read flowfile data and call another processor based pre-processor data.
example:- kafka consumer read data (processor) ---> flowfile(collection id) --> Getmongo (processor) get data from mongo based on pre processor data (collection id). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You can use `ExtractText` , `RouteOnContent`  nifi processors to access content of flowfile using expression language. `ExecuteScript ` also used to access content of the incoming flowfile.

Comment: refer these templates
1. [convert a CSV entry to a JSON document using ExtractText and ReplaceText](https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/nifi-templates/blob/master/templates/csv-to-json-flow.xml)

2. [Apache NiFi template to demonstrate `RouteOnContent` capabilities.](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/c7e549e424a508b967c91d2f59aa4a42)

3. [ExecuteScript Cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922)

4. [NiFi ExecuteScript Samples](https://github.com/SherifEldeeb/nifi-executescript-samples)

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Thanks for answer, but my requirement is little different, I want to create dynamic mongo query in second processor and that query prepared based on flowfile data (collection-id). Is it Possible ?.

Comment: certainly, you can use `UpdateAttribute` processor to updates the Attributes for a FlowFile by using the Attribute Expression Language and/or deletes the attributes based on a regular expression.

`ExtractText` processor, adding a custom attribute with a value set to the regular expression "(.*)".

[create a new attribute with value as the content of the flowfile](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-create-a-new-attribute-with-value-as-the-content-of/td-p/107335)

Answer (score 0):

you can use UpdateAttribute processor to updates the Attributes for a FlowFile by using the Attribute Expression Language and/or deletes the attributes based on a regular expression. ExtractText processor, adding a custom attribute with a value set to the regular expression "(.*)". create a new attribute with value as the content of the flowfile